# House on Orchard

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I built my home on my parents's orchard. The parcel is mine. They take the harvest profits. I want them. What should I do if I'm non-confrontational?

---

My name is on the title. There is no legally binding crop agreement. I respect my parents. They want to keep the profits too. What are my legal options (California)?

Comment: Clever disclaimer, but [please review the meta discussions on this, and perhaps contribute your idea there](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/search?q=disclaimer).  Also, it is unclear how this is a legal question, as opposed to an ethical or negotiation question.  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Would contribute if I had the reputation to...

Comment: You'll have the rep with one good question or answer.  Remove the disclaimer in the meantime.  And I still don't understand the question: The law says you can take whatever you want, and you are looking for an option to do so without doing so?

Comment: Is this house on your parents' orchard or not?

Comment: The orchard was put in place by my parents, yes. The land upon which the orchard grows is, however, within the property polygon of which I am the title owner of.

Comment: So basically they've been harvesting the place for a number of years. Then they somehow created a property polygon, gave it you, and which you built a home on. Now they keep harvesting the place but now it includes the trees on your property. You are asking if there is a legal option that you are not considering. What legal options ARE you considering?

Comment: That is correct. It's family. It's political. It's moot. What I meant was "What options do I have?"

Comment: This site can only help you with the legal options. There are sites that deal with ethical questions.

Comment: You need to research "prescriptive easement." If you tell them to stop maintaining and harvesting the orchard, but they continue, after five years, they could sue to establish a prescriptive easement. You could allow them an easement instead, which you could then revoke later.

Comment: You should consider editing the question so that the first part is no longer so open-ended ("What should I do?" questions are primarily opinion-based anyway and not constructive).